# oversampling (SMOTE) does not work properly when fitted inside a pipeline

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, classification, imbalanced-data, oversampling

I have an imbalanced classification problem and I am using `make_pipeline` from `imblearn`

So the steps are the following:

```
kf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, random_state=42, shuffle=True)
params = {
    'max_depth': [2,3,5],
#     'max_features':['auto', 'sqrt', 'log2'],
#     'min_samples_leaf': [5,10,20,50,100,200,300],
    'n_estimators': [10,25,30,50]
#     'bootstrap': [True, False]

}
from imblearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
imba_pipeline = make_pipeline(SMOTE(random_state = 42), RobustScaler(), RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42)) 
imba_pipeline

out:Pipeline(steps=[('smote', SMOTE(random_state=42)),
                ('robustscaler', RobustScaler()),
                ('randomforestclassifier',
                 RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42))])

new_params = {'randomforestclassifier__' + key: params[key] for key in params}
grid_imba = GridSearchCV(imba_pipeline, param_grid=new_params, cv=kf, scoring='recall',
                        return_train_score=True, n_jobs=-1, verbose=2)

grid_imba.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

And everything is going ok and I am reaching to the end to by problem (i.e I can see the classification report)

However when I am trying to see inside the black box with `eli5` with `eli.explain_weights(imba_pipeline)`

I get back as error

```
TypeError: All intermediate steps should be transformers and implement fit and transform or be the string 'passthrough' 'SMOTE(random_state=42)' (type <class 'imblearn.over_sampling._smote.SMOTE'>) doesn't
```

I know that this Is a common problem and i have read the related questions but i am confused as the problem  is occurred after the end of my classification procedure

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should link to the related questions you've read, and explain briefly why each one doesn't seem to apply to your situation.

Comment: What about passing only the randomforest to eli5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pipeline has two fitted steps (+ the scaler): the SMOTE augmentation and the random forest. It looks like this is confusing the eli5 which wants to work with the assumptions that only the last layer is fitted. To get the weight explanation of the random forest you could try calling `eli5` only on that layer of the pipeline with

```py
from eli5 import explain_weights

explain_weights(imba_pipeline['randomforestclassifier'])
```

provided the pipeline is fitted, but in your code you were fitting the grid search so

```py
explain_weights(grid_imba.best_estimator_['randomforestclassifier'])
```

would be more appropriate.

Comment: i get back NotFittedError: This RandomForestClassifier instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator.

Comment: Looking at your code you fitted grid search but not the pipeline. I suggest you add `refit=True` to the grid search parameters. Then use `explain_weights(grid_imba.best_estimator_['randomforestclassifier'])`

Comment: Actually `refit=True` is the default value, according to https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html so you only need the replacement I suggested

Comment: ok please remove your statement: "Since the pipeline is not fitted at all in your code sample" to avoid any confusions

Comment: Have edited the text to explain both cases

Comment: Also, you said that "Your pipeline has two fitted steps: the SMOTE augmentation and the random forest". However, has three steps included the robust scaler

Comment: Ah true that, the scaler does fit too, interestingly it does not both eli5 though.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to point out that SMOTE generally doesn't improve prediction quality. See https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.08528

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).